# Deep Zoom Collection in Javascript Canvas

Tags: javascript, ajax, deepzoom, seadragon

I need to create a deep zoom mosaic in an HTML5 Canvas Element with thousands of roughly 512x512 images, but I want to reinvent the wheel as little as possible.

So rather than combining tons and tons of large images into one then creating a Deep Zoom Image, I'd rather make a load of deep zoom images and create a Deep Zoom Collection, but Seadragon doesn't support the DZC format.

The way I see it I have three other options, which are

1. Start from scratch, create a viewer which deals with loading DZC files
2. Extend Seadragon to allow it to handle DZC files
3. Create some way to parse the DCZ file, process it's relevant images and turn it into a huge DZI file

I was hoping I could get a bit of advice here, maybe a sounding board from someone with more experience in Deep Zoom and the XML format it uses to recommend which would be the easiest and best considering I have a tight deadline.

Any advice would be awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a specific reason for using HTML5 canvas element? If you just want something that works without any extra plugin's why not use [CanvasZoom](http://www.akademy.co.uk/software/canvaszoom/canvaszoom.php)

Comment: AFAIK, CanvasZoom only supports a DZI (single image), not a DZC (collection of images you can select and overlap individually like in MS' PhotoSynth project).  Not working in MSIE is a big killer too until MS fixes their crap HTML5 support :-P